# Vertically align two images using left/right alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a left div and a right div, and within this whole row of these two divs I want all of the divs to be vertically centered which I had working at one point like this:

[image]

**Now, however, it looks like this:**

[image]

The only change I made was I changed the "More Info" buttons from `input` tags to `img` tags with `a` tags, as I realized these buttons needed to go to a different target. Here is the html of one of the rows:

```
<div class="centervertically">
                <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <div class="alignleft">
                        <div class="leftInnerDiv featureh5">
                            Front page app listing &nbsp;<b>$9.99</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alignright">
                        <div class="rightInnerDiv">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="PHV69C7ZY5GMG">
                        <input type="image" src="http://www.appninja.io/images/addtocart.png" width="130" height="43" border="0" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                        <a href="marketing.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.appninja.io/images/moreinfo.png" width="130" height="43" border="0" border="0"></a>
                        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> 
                    </div>        
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

And here is the CSS associated with it:

```
.centervertically,
.alignleft,
.alignright{
    height: 60px;
}

.alignleft:before,
.alignright:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.leftInnerDiv,
.rightInnerDiv{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}

.featureh5 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: There's a mistake in the markup (`div` not closed?). Please provide a jsFiddle if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` tag is inline. You should put `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` to it.